# how to prevent hibernate JPA delete entity with one to many foreign key occurence like on delete restrict on spring repository

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, delete-row

I have the following situation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workspaces")
data class Workspace (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var id: Long = 0,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workspace")
    var applicationList: MutableList<Application> = arrayListOf())

@Entity
@Table(name = "applications")
data class Application (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var id: Long? = null,


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workspace_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var workspace: Workspace)
```

If I have a row in the table application that referenced a row in the table workspace, how can I prevent Spring repository to delete that workspace row during a `workspaceRepository.deleteById(workspaceId)` operation? I want something like on delete restrict rule. I would like that an exception is thrown.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem atm